# Angular: communicating to a child component when its in router-outlet

Tags: angular, parent-child

I got a basic app: a top bar and a general area: (this is a simplified HTML version, from app.component.html)

```
<header>
    <app-top-bar >

    </app-top-bar>
</header>
<main>
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <router-outlet></router-outlet>    
    </div>
</main>
```

now: in the app-top-bar I got an INPUT used as a general search - and the search will be applied on whatever component will come in real time inside router-outlet. I need, therefore, to let the child component "know" (via calling a method on it or any other mechanism) that a search term has been entered.

Now I know how a parent an communicate with a child (@input, @ViewChild...) but how do I do it in this scenario - communicating with a child that keeps changing depending on user navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `ServiceService` on root level providing a `search(...)` method and a `searchChanges()` method returning an observable. Then simply inject the service into components that support the global search listen for search changes.

#### search.service.ts

```
@Inject({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SearchService {
    private readonly searchChanges$ = new Subject<string>();

    search(text: string): void {
        this.searchChanges$.next(text);
    }

    searchChanges(): Observable<string> { 
        return this.searchChanges$.asObservable();
    }
}
```

#### top-bar.component.ts

```
@Component({ 
    selector: 'app-top-bar',
    ...
})
export class TopBarComponent {

    constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {
    }

    onSearch(text: string): void {
        this.searchService.search(text);
    }
}
```

#### other.component.ts

```
@Component({ 
    selector: 'app-other',
    ...
})
export class OtherComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.searchService.searchChanges().subscribe(text => {
            // Handle search here
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work! thanks!